# How to align two columns perfectly in python?

Tags: python, alignment, multiple-columns

I have an assignment where we have to read the file we created that has the test names and scores and print them in columns. Getting the data and displaying it, along with the average, is no problem, but I do not understand how to align the scores to the right in the output column. In the output example the scores line up perfectly to the right of the "SCORES" column. I can format their width using format(scores, '10d') as an example, but that's always relative to how long the name of the test was. Any advice?

```
   def main():
       testAndscores = open('tests.txt', 'r')
       totalTestscoresVaule = 0 
       numberOfexams = 0 
       line = testAndscores.readline() 
       print("Reading  tests and scores")
       print("============================")
       print("TEST     SCORES")
       while line != "":
              examName = line.rstrip('\n')
              testScore = float(testAndscores.readline())
              totalTestscoresVaule += testScore


              ## here is where I am having problems
              ## can't seem to find info how to align into
              ## two columns.
              print(format(examName),end="")           
              print(format(" "),end="")
              print(repr(testScore).ljust(20))

              line = testAndscores.readline()
              numberOfexams += 1   
              averageOftheTestscores = totalTestscoresVaule / numberOfexams
              print("Average is", (averageOftheTestscores))  

              #close the file
              testAndscores.close()

   main()
```

Comment: Get a list of all lines; find the longest "scores"; calculate the width of the column and use it in the format.

Comment: Maybe libraries like [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) or [terminaltables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/terminaltables) could help you. There are a lot of like these.

Comment: can you provide example of tests.txt

Comment: @DYZ That sounds like a great idea! Could you provide an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to store each name and score in a list, then calculate the longest name, and use this length to print space for shorter name.

```
def main():
    with open('tests.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = []
        totalTestscoresVaule = 0
        numberOfexams = 0

        while True:
            exam_name = f.readline().rstrip('\n')

            if exam_name == "":
                break

            line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
            test_score = float(line)
            totalTestscoresVaule += test_score

            data.append({'name': exam_name, 'score': test_score})

            numberOfexams += 1
            averageOftheTestscores = totalTestscoresVaule / numberOfexams

        longuest_test_name = max([len(d['name']) for d in data])

        print("Reading  tests and scores")
        print("============================")
        print("TEST{0} SCORES".format(' ' * (longuest_test_name - 4)))

        for d in data:
            print(format(d['name']), end=" ")
            print(format(" " * (longuest_test_name - len(d['name']))), end="")
            print(repr(d['score']).ljust(20))

        print("Average is", (averageOftheTestscores))


main()
```